# Getting a value in the subquery postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which looks like this:

```
select id,name 
  from table1 as one 
 where one.duration < (select min(duration) from table2 where one.id = id)
```

Table2 contains a column called outcome and I would like to display it in the outer query. Table1 and Table2 have no relationship except for the fact that they both contain the column id.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: seems `duration` is another common column for both tables

Answer (score 0):

You need a `HAVING` Clause including comparison of aggregated values for `duration` column together with `GROUP BY` expression :

```
SELECT t1.id, name, outcome
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
 GROUP BY t1.id, name, outcome
 HAVING MAX(t1.duration) < MIN(t2.duration)
```

Comment: the id column is not primary key foreign key relation column. In other words, the id column appears multiple times in the table1 and table2

Comment: so what ....  @bangbang ? you can replace with proper id columns from each tables due to primary-foreign key relationship.

Comment: Oh! So, t2.id = t1.id won't make sense in this case.

Comment: t1.id  = t2.id works if the id column was a unique column in t1.But in my scenario, it's not and I need to loop through each and every column in t1. So I can't really use distinct here.

Comment: distinct would be redundant in this case as already having `group by`